# Como realizar ajax porem não atualizar conteúdo da div so adicionar?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Tenho um `<div>` onde o retorno da função `ajax` e retornada, porem ela se atualiza, quero saber se tem como realizar a função `ajax` e no lugar de atualizar ela trazer o resultado deixando o resultado antigo, é possível?

HTML

```
<div id="id">

</div>
```

Ajax

```
  $.ajax({
         url:'enviar.php',
         method:'POST',
         data:{nome:nome, texto:texto},
         beforeSend: function(){
          $("#id").html("...");
         }
         success:function(data){
          $("#id").html(data)
         }

        });
```

Comment: Poderia postar como está o seu código até o momento?

Comment: Da pagina que envia o ajax ou a que recebe?

Comment: Provavelmente `$("#id").append(data)` já resolverá

Comment: Resolveu mais uma duvida se eu colocar um beforeSend $("#id").append("...") os 3 pontos também fica como faço para não ficar os 3 pontos?

Comment: @abfurlan adiciona sua resposta para eu colocar como respondida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa alterar `$("#id").html(data)` para `$("#id").append(data)`.